# liferay 6.0.6: cannot upload .xlsx file larger than about 6 MB (but .xls file works)

Tags: liferay, xlsx

I have an Excel 2007 file (.xlsx) of about 6 MB filesize.

From within our company network I cannot upload this 6 MB file into Liferay's document library. Neither the GUI-based upload form works, nor the webdav-based upload. If I rename the file to (.xls) then I can upload it in a couple of seconds, there is no problem whatsoever.

However, In the liferay doclib backend, I also cannot *rename back* the file from .xls  to .xlsx. If I try to do so, then the server hangs for a while. There is no entry in the error log. When I try to do the renaming on a dev server/my local machine, the liferay server consumes all available memory and I have to run a "killall java" command from an unresponsive terminal.

I can, however, upload .xlsx files of, say, 2 MB size. All filename extensions are allowed to be uploaded. Only "larger" .xlsx files are problematic.

liferay 6.0.6

```
Used memory:    176.528.048 Bytes
Total memory:   283.590.656 Bytes
maximum memory:     1.069.416.448 Bytes 

env.CATALINA_HOME   /opt/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29
env.CATALINA_OPTS   -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true 

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx1024m  -XX:PermSize=42m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.timezone=GMT+2 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jaas.config -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

WHat makes .xlsx files so special?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question - did you try changing the maximum file size settings in Control Panel->Server Administration->File Uploads-> Document Library - Maximum file and allowed extension.

Also try to see if adding a temporary storage directory helps.

Comment: yes as I said, xls Files (Excel 2003) larger than 5 MB are no problem, only .xlsx Files > 5 MB are a problem. We assume that lucene cannot deal with it. xlsx files are basically zip files, and all indexing has to be done in memory